# iOS: How to cover status bar with container view

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uiview-hierarchy

I have following view hierarchy in my main view controller:

**Main view** -> **Container view** -> **Page view controller in container view** -> **Item view controller for every page**

I need to make item view controller to place his view above status bar of main view controller. I've added constraint from container view's top to main view's top (not to top layout guide):

[image: top constraint]

But item view controller places his view (green one on picture) under status bar anyway:

[image: green view]

Can I do something to get needed behaviour? I need the status bar to be covered by view from item view controller, not by any view from other view controllers.

Thanks.

Comment: Do that in storyboard. Drag element till it covers everything, and add constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In storyboard set the top constraint to `view` not to top safeAreas / topLayoutGuide

Comment: Yea, got it, I've set it in main controller, but should do it in the controller from container view too.